# How do I read next line with BufferedReader in Java?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, readline

I have a text file. I want to read it line by line and turn it into an 2-dimensional array. I have written something as follows:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("num.txt"));
String line = br.readLine();

while( line != null) {                
    System.out.printf(line);  
}
```

This turns into an infinite loop. I want to move on to the next line after I'm done with reading and printing a line. But I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You only read the first line.  The `line` variable didn't change in the `while` loop, leading to the infinite loop.

Read the next line in the `while` condition, so each iteration reads a line, changing the variable.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("num.txt"));
String line;

while( (line = br.readLine() ) != null) {
    System.out.printf(line);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("num.txt"));
String line = br.readLine();

while( line != null) {

    System.out.printf(line);

    // read the next line
    line = br.readLine();
}
```

... or read the line in the while condition (as rgettman pointed out):

```
String line;
while( (line = br.readLine()) != null) {

    System.out.printf(line);

}
```