# How do I read the next line BufferedReader?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I'm having a problem where it doesn't read the next line after I retrieve the first line. The main issue is that after I get the first line of data from my txt file which is basically this:

```
admin,password  
nameone,passtwo  
nametwo,passthree
```

etc. etc.

The problem I have is that it doesn't read after `admin,password`. How could this be fixed?

```
else if (userName.equals(u) && passWord.equals(p)) {  
    http.setAttribute("username", userName);  
    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/inventory.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

That line of code is supposed to read the data after the first line but I'm not too sure on how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        HttpSession http = request.getSession();

        String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/users.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(path)));

        String userName = request.getParameter("username");
        String passWord = request.getParameter("password");

        String account = br.readLine();
        String split[] = account.split(",");

        int i = 0;
        String u = split[i];
        String p = split[i + 1];

        while ((account = br.readLine()) != null) {

            if (userName.equals(u) && passWord.equals(p)) {
                http.setAttribute("username", userName);
                getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/admin.jsp").forward(request, response);
                // response.sendRedirect("inventory");
            } else if (userName.equals(u) && passWord.equals(p)) {
                http.setAttribute("username", userName);
                getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/inventory.jsp").forward(request, response);
            } else {
                request.setAttribute("message", "The wrong username or password have been entered.");
                getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/login.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }
            account = br.readLine();
        }

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("username", userName);
        response.sendRedirect("inventory");
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28999757/how-do-i-read-next-line-with-bufferedreader-in-java#:~:text=Read%20the%20next%20line%20in%20the%20whilecondition%2C%20so,BufferedReader%20br%20%3D%20new%20BufferedReader%20%28new%20FileReader%20%28%22num.txt%22%29%29%3B

Comment: You aren't splitting the string you just read inside the loop, so `userName` and `passWord` are never changing. You're also reading twice within the loop, so you will miss every other line. Why you're testing them twice is another mystery.

Comment: You are also not closing the reader - use a "try-with-resources" block. Using `Files.readAllLines` is a lot simpler than `BufferedReader`

Answer (score 1):

```
 while ((account = br.readLine()) != null) {
            account = br.readLine(); //duplicated here.
        }
```

From your code, you readLine twice . You should remove the end command.

```
 while ((account = br.readLine()) != null) {             
        }
```

It's enough. You can print account for debugging to make sure if you suspect the data.

By the way, two if conditions are the same. Please refactor your code...

Answer (score 0):

You never refresh the actual values, only read the line and do nothing with them. Fix:

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        HttpSession http = request.getSession();

        String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/users.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(path)));

        String userName = request.getParameter("username");
        String passWord = request.getParameter("password");

        String account = "", u = "", p = "";

        while ((account = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String split[] = account.split(",");

        int i = 0;
        u = split[i];
        p = split[i + 1];

            if (userName.equals(u) && passWord.equals(p)) {
                http.setAttribute("username", userName);
                getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/admin.jsp").forward(request, response);
                // response.sendRedirect("inventory");
            } else if (userName.equals(u) && passWord.equals(p)) {
                http.setAttribute("username", userName);
                getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/inventory.jsp").forward(request, response);
            } else {
                request.setAttribute("message", "The wrong username or password have been entered.");
                getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/login.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }
            account = br.readLine();
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you really want to check whether BufferedReader is not't working.
Work this code.I think if The code is complex,You had better test of part.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String path = "useres.txt";
    File file = new File(path);
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    String account = null;
    while ((account = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(account);
    }

    br.close();
}
```

output is

```
admin,password
nameone,passtwo
nametwo,passthree
etc,etc
```