# Append a string to an XML file

Tags: java, file

I have an XML file and String data. I want to add the String in XML file. How can I open the XML file and append String before XML syntax start?

Below is the XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<AppHdr xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.02">
    -<Fr>
        -<FIId>
            -<Fin>
                <BIC>AAA</BIC>
            </Fin>
        </FIId>
    </Fr>
</AppHdr>
```

String value="Hello Append with xml";

Final output

```
Hello Append with xml<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<AppHdr xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.02">
-<Fr>
-<FIId>
-<Fin>
<BIC>AAA</BIC>
</Fin>
</FIId>
</Fr>
</AppHdr>
```

Comment: This would result in an invalid xml file, so why does it matter what the extension is or how to open an xml file from any other? You write the string to a file, then just write all bytes of another file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
try {
  File mFile = new File("C:\\name.xml");//path to file with name of file
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(mFile);
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
  StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("Hello Append with xml");
  String line = "";
  while( (line = br.readLine()) != null){
    result.append(line);
    result.append(System.lineSeparator());
  }

  mFile.delete();
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(mFile);
  fos.write(result.toString().getBytes());
  fos.flush();
} catch (IOException e) {
  //exception handling
}
```

Comment: This will remove all the newlines.

Comment: @Unmitigated why?

Comment: Because `br.readLine` does not return newlines. Try the code yourself.

Comment: @Unmitigated I tried and it worked.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28999757/how-do-i-read-next-line-with-bufferedreader-in-java

Comment: No, it removes all the newline characters. See the documentation for [`BufferedReader#readLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--): "Returns:
A String containing the contents of the line, **not including any line-termination characters**, or null if the end of the stream has been reached"

Comment: Ok, but it won't remove all the newlines, it create one line

Comment: That's the exact same as removing all the newlines. The previous code discards the newlines and places the entire output on one line, which is not the expected output in the question.

Comment: Good to see you've edited your answer. Note that `System.getProperty("line.separator")` can be replaced with `System.lineSeparator()`.

Comment: @Unmitigated good suggestion, thanks